# web scraping for data

Tags: node.js, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I get a

> referenceError: Terminal A is not defined

on line 48. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
writeStream.write(`Terminal A,Terminal B,Terminal C/D \n`);


var minutes = 1, timerInerval = minutes * 60 * 1000;


function TerminalOccupancyData() {

 
  request('https://www.laguardiaairport.com/to-from-airport/parking', (error, response, html) => {
    // Check there is no error
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      // using cheerio library to load the website page html
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      $('.terminal-left').each((span, el) => {
        // Find the element using the class
        const terminalA = $(el)
          .find('.terminal-percentage')
          .text()
          .replace(/% Full/, '');

        const terminalB = $(el)
          .find('.terminal-percentage')
          .text()
          .replace(/% Full/, '');

        const terminalCD = $(el)
          .find('.terminal-percentage')
          .text()
          .replace(/% Full/, '');
      });

      console.log('\nTerminal Data scraped ... \n');
    }

  });

  // Export to file to upload to database
  writeStream.write(`${terminalA},${terminalB},${terminalCD} \n`);
}

setInterval(TerminalOccupancyData, timerInerval);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having here is that your `writeStream.write(...)` is not inside of the same scope as the variables it's referencing. Since you're not trying to return any values from the outer function, I believe what will solve your problem is simply moving that statement inside the `.each()` callback function, like so:

```
function TerminalOccupancyData() {

 
  request('https://www.laguardiaairport.com/to-from-airport/parking', (error, response, html) => {
    // Check there is no error
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      // using cheerio library to load the website page html
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      $('.terminal-left').each((span, el) => {
        // Find the element using the class
        const terminalA = $(el)
          .find('.terminal-percentage')
          .text()
          .replace(/% Full/, '');

        const terminalB = $(el)
          .find('.terminal-percentage')
          .text()
          .replace(/% Full/, '');

        const terminalCD = $(el)
          .find('.terminal-percentage')
          .text()
          .replace(/% Full/, '');

          // Export to file to upload to database
          writeStream.write(`${terminalA},${terminalB},${terminalCD} \n`);
      });

      console.log('\nTerminal Data scraped ... \n');

    }

  });

  
}

setInterval(TerminalOccupancyData, timerInerval);
```

Comment: Thanks. It resolved the issue but I am not grabbing the data into the csv